# EntityManager null when used in S

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa, ejb

Consider following class:

```
package com.deluxe.common.dao;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.deluxe.jpa.Customer;

@ManagedBean(name="jpaBean")
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class JpaDao  {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="EmployeeService")
    EntityManager em;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }


    public void addEmployee(String name, String lastName) {

        Customer cust = new Customer();

        cust.setName(name);
        cust.setLastName(lastName);

        em.persist(cust);
    }

}
```

When I call a addEmployee through JSF managed bean then entitymanager is null but when I print entitymanager in jsf bean its shows up. Here is the code of jsf managed bean:

```
@EJB JpaDao psb;

    public void addCustomer() {
        EntityManager em = psb.getEntityManager();
        JpaDao jpa = new JpaDao();
        jpa.addEmployee("Some..", "Thing..");   // Throwing err, em in JpaDao is null.
        System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"+em);  //This line show em is there.
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        cust.setLastName("Krishnawat");
        cust.setName("Nagendra");
        em.persist(cust);
    }
```

Why it is so ? Am I missing something.

Comment: Have you worked with EJBs before now? Why have you chosen to instantiate your `JpaDao`?

Answer (score -1):

I see that you didn't declare private your entitymanager and your ejb JpaDao, and I think it is a bad habit. I think you can begin to try set private your entityManager, put the corresponding getter and setter which will respect the convention, and try again. Because I have some problem with another attribute and it was because something like that

Comment: No, Its not because of that, the answer is I need to put @Local on top of bean to indicate weather its local or remote bean.